# Meteor - Autoform set endDate to read present

Tags: meteor

I'm using autoform and I have two date fields, startDate and endDate. Most of the time there will be an endDate however in certain circumstance the user will need to set the end date to 'present'.

For instance, if you are currently studying a subject and have not completed it, there would be a startDate and the endDate that would say something like 'currently studying'.

Is there a way to do this?

Path: `Schemas.js`

```
Schema.Dates = new SimpleSchema({
    startDate: {
        type: Date,  
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "bootstrap-datepicker",
            "data-date-autoclose": "true",
            datePickerOptions: {
               format: "MMM yyyy",
               startView: "months",
               minViewMode: "months"
            }
        }    
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Date,  
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "bootstrap-datepicker",
            "data-date-autoclose": "true",
            datePickerOptions: {
               format: "mm/yyyy",
               startView: "months",
               minViewMode: "months"
            }
        }     
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Set the todayBtn option to true.

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#todaybtn

Edit: update after more detail given

Try this.

```
Schema.Dates = new SimpleSchema({
    startDate: {
        type: Date,  
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "bootstrap-datepicker",
            "data-date-autoclose": "true",
            datePickerOptions: {
               format: "MMM yyyy",
               startView: "months",
               minViewMode: "months"
            }
        }    
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Date,  
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "bootstrap-datepicker",
            "data-date-autoclose": "true",
            datePickerOptions: {
               format: "mm/yyyy",
               startView: "months",
               minViewMode: "months"
            }
        }     
    },
    inProgress: {
        type: Boolean,
        optional: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @JoshJoe . I don't think that's the solution I need. Please correct me if I wrong but the 'today' button will just set today's date. What I want to do is have the end date say 'present'. For instance, if you are currently studying a subject and have not completed it, there would be a startDate and the endDate that would say something like 'currently studying'.

Comment: OK, yes, in that case you might consider adding an inProgress Boolean to your schema. Set it to true when there is a start date, but no end date.